# Recover slightly corrupted Windows XP drive with Linux

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, ntfs, filesystem-corruption

I installed Linux and that involved shrinking a Windows NTFS partition. I didn't move it, just shrinked it a hair. When I rebooted windows, it said "Disk can not be read". I booted my Lubuntu and mounted the drive. Linux can read the drive perfectly fine. I wonder why Windows can't. Perhaps this is yet another flaw in the design. I hate windows, but I need to recover it. I have all of the personal data, I just need the OS back again. I am on a Compaq, so there is an entire partition devoted to a recovery OS for Windows. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the recovery utility that came with my computer. It did not find anything wrong with my drives, but I knew that there was something wrong so I backed up my personal data, and did a Destructive Recovery. That sets EVERYTHING back to system defaults that came with the computer. I then restored my personal data and I am quite happy!